# How to add hr after each p? using the loop for

Tags: javascript

```
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((elem) => {
elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<hr/>');
});

<article>
<h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
<p>First</p>
<h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
<p>Second</p>
<h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
<p>Third</p>
```

It is not possible to modify the specified markup

Comment: Your code is working, but you need to execute JS after the page load. Attaching a sample code in answetr

Comment: Yes, but to avoid the foreach method, but with the loop

Comment: Do you mean you want to achieve this via ```for``` loop?

Comment: yes, i mean with using the loop `for`

Comment: Just updated my answer, check..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p');

for(let item of Array.from(paragraphs)) {
  const hr = document.createElement("hr");                
  item.appendChild(hr)
}
```

```html
<h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
<p>First</p>
<h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
<p>Second</p>
<h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
<p>Third</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
       var element = document.querySelectorAll('p');
       for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
           element[i].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<hr/>');
       }

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
        <p>First</p>
        <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
        <p>Second</p>
        <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
        <p>Third</p>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems to work just fine. Just be wary of using the getElementsByTagName as it will select ALL p tags on the page and not just the three you have in your example.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('p').forEach((elem) => {
elem.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<hr/>');
});
```

```html
<h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
<p>First</p>
<h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
<p>Second</p>
<h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
<p>Third</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

before close article tag :) and then use 2 Way:

1. use CSS (simple & best)  [Show sample in jsfiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/s1yrno7v/)
2. or use array in javascript

```js
Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("p")).forEach(function(e, i) {
  e.append(document.createElement("hr"));
});
```

```html
<article>
  <h3>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h3>
  <p>First</p>
  <h3>Where does it come from?</h3>
  <p>Second</p>
  <h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
  <p>Third</p>
</article>
```